# JavaScript: Best practices for DOM-reliant code executed both server & client-side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, single-page-application, browserify

**Background**

Starting a little over 2 years ago (with [Batman.js](http://batmanjs.org/) & [node.js](http://nodejs.org/)) I began experimenting with having the same DOM code executed on the server and client. This is desired to have SPAs (single-page applications) that can be rendered using `pushState` and be accessed at routes with page already rendered for SEO and for superior user experience (none of the page "flash" associated with SPAs rendering elements after the page loads). This usually involves wrapping modules in `if` statements that check if the module is being executed in `window` or being required using [require.js](http://requirejs.org/), or as a module in [node.js](http://nodejs.org/), et al.

**Current Implementations of Client+Server SPAs**

[Rendr](https://github.com/airbnb/rendr) & [Ezel](http://ezeljs.com/) both attempt to help bring client+server code sharing and DOM rendering functionality to Backbone SPAs. [Ezel](http://ezeljs.com/) has magic with the Backbone models/collections, but the views are rendered using [Express](http://expressjs.com/)+[Jade](http://jade-lang.com/) on the server while using [Backbone.View](http://backbonejs.org/#View) + [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/) on the client. That means that using something like [Rivets](http://www.rivetsjs.com/) in your extended Backbone.View won't result in the HTML hitting the client pre-rendered by [Rivets](http://www.rivetsjs.com/). I'd like to build some best practices and techniques for rendering a DOM server-side myself to keep things straightforward (edit the view code in one place) and flexible (be able to add additional DOM manipulation modules that Ezel doesn't currently support).

**The Desired Result**

I'd like to use something like [Rivets](http://www.rivetsjs.com/) to inject model data into the view before the page is served to the browser from [Express](http://expressjs.com/) when a route is hit for a full page load via a HTTP request, and also be bound to respond to changes via `pushState` on the client. What are the environment requirements in node for me to be able to use [Rivets](http://www.rivetsjs.com/) to modify HTML on the server before it's served and stay bound on the client? How do I best bring in [jQuery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery), [Backbone](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone), [Rivets](http://www.rivetsjs.com/) etc. into [node.js](http://nodejs.org/), have them run on the DOM of an HTML template, and then serve the results pre-rendered (while maintaining the normal JS behavior on the client thereafter)?

**Related Modules**

[Sharify](https://github.com/artsy/sharify) & [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) are both tools that can also help with sharing code between the sides. [Rivets](http://www.rivetsjs.com/), [Backbone](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone) & [jQuery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery) all have node.js-compatible distributions.

**Current Work**

I've begun work on adding functionality to [Ezel](http://ezeljs.com/) via a [fork on Github](https://github.com/sony-magic/ezel).

Comment: I would highly recommend looking in to ReactJS to do exactly this kind of thing if you haven't already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to achieve having a near-pure isomorphic JavaScript application by building on top of Ezel with jsdom. jsdom incurs a performance hit so I cached the result of running rivets on the server when possible.

I took some cues from https://github.com/adjohnson916/rivets-server. I was unable to use that module wholesale because it stomps on several of the configuration options I needed to send to rivets (rivets-server uses a fork of rivets).

One of the pitfalls I initially hit was related to using Sharify & Rivets at the same time. Sharify injects a script into your webpage that contains a function and that tripped up rivets because it uses {} for templating. By changing `templateDelimiters` to double curly brackets, I circumvented the issue.

The main components of an isomorphic JavaScript application are:

- A module that shims in node.js environment elements for the browser, including `require` (e.g. Browserify)
- The ability to use a first-run of your data-binding library on the server (e.g. jsdom running rivets). Using this rather than Ezel's method of using node-jadeify (which I contributed to) is superior to Ezel, where rendering must happen in different ways in two different files.
- A module that abstracts away the differences in HTTP requests client v. server (e.g. backbone-super-sync)
- A module that enables you to share configuration data between client & server (e.g. sharify)

Comment: Thanks for referencing https://github.com/adjohnson916/rivets-server (from me, the author). Please file issues on GitHub if you are interested in having it support whatever configuration options it's missing.